# Make JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to make a list of JSON objects in python I have an list of keys, and a list of items, so keys is something like this, by the way I am getting this list from the web so it is always a single quote

```
keys = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

and then items something like this

```
rows = [[foo, fuu, fhh], [bar, bat, bak]]
```

And what I want is

```
[{"one":"foo", "two":"fuu", "three":"fhb"},
{"one":"bar", "two":"bat", "three":"bak"}]
```

And here is what I am trying but I end up with this

```
['{"one":"foo", "two":"fuu", "three":"fhb"}',
'{"one":"bar", "two":"bat", "three":"bak"}']
```

Which makes it no longer valid JSON:

```
results = []
info = {}
for row in items:
    i = 0
    for item in row:
        info[keys[i]] = item
        data = json.dumps(info)
        i += 1
    results.append(data)
```

So how can I get rid of those single quotes and just have double quotes and valid JSON?

Thanks

Comment: You're making a list of strings. Make a list, *then* `dumps` it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `json.dumps` you create a json string that can be written to a file that represents your data. You should create the list and then, at the end, use `json.dumps` to create your json.

You could also use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to make your code more readable:

```
>>> results = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in rows]
>>> print results

[{'one': 'foo', 'three': 'fhh', 'two': 'fuu'},
 {'one': 'bar', 'three': 'bak', 'two': 'bat'}]

>>> json.dumps(results)

'[{"three": "fhh", "two": "fuu", "one": "foo"}, {"three": "bak", "two": "bat", "one": "bar"}]'
```

Comment: Much more Pythonic than the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `json.dumps` at the end, not at each iteration:

```
results = []
for row in items:
    i = 0
    info = {}
    for item in row:
        info[keys[i]] = item
        i += 1
    results.append(info)

return json.dumps(results)
```

It will first construct your list of strings and then serialize the Python object as a JSON one.

Comment: okay now that I have after the `json.dumps` I get this `final_result =[{"one":"foo", "two":"fuu", "three":"fhb"},
{"one":"bar", "two":"bat", "three":"bak"}]` how could I just get the first JSON because final_result[0] doesn't work?

Comment: I don't understand what you want then. Why do you want a JSON object if it is for accessing items after via Python syntax?

`results` is a Python object: you can do `results[0]['one']` (which returns foo). With `json.dump(results)` you get a JSON representation of the list of dict. You need to do `json.loads` before to be able to use it as a Python object again.

Comment: @spenf10 Agree with Maxime. If you're going to try to use the data when you're done, you don't want JSON. You just want the `list` of `dict`s without converting to JSON. JSON is strictly text data, usually used for exchanging data between two different systems (like between a web application and a browser).